# SQL sum total price of products except HP and Toshiba

Tags: mysql, sql, product

I need to display  the total price of all products **except** HP and Toshiba products. Below is a picture of the  products table

[image: picture of the products table]

Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?? show us your query and issue if you are facing any...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select sum(price)
  from products 
  where prod_name not like 'Toshiba%' 
  and prod_name not like 'HP%';
```

This will exclude all the products where the name starts with Toshiba or HP.

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46d78/3)